# i am tried for readin a csv file using python and wish to store values into MySQL,but now i am meeting some errors

Tags: python, mysql

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import sys
import csv

csvfile='/home/arun/Documents/smartearn/Linux/SA/xbrlparser/UGT-2012-Concepts.csv'
def csvparsing():

    spamReader = csv.reader(open(csvfile, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    header=spamReader.next()

    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                           user = "arunkamaly",
                           db = "se")



    cursor=conn.cursor()
    for clist in spamReader:
        name=clist[1]+clist[2]
        cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO se_xbrl_concepts( xbrl_id,xbrl_name,xbrl_type,Xbrl_enumerations,Xbrl_substitutiongroup,Xbrl_balance, Xbrl_periodtype, Xbrl_IsAbstract,xbrl_label,Xbrl_desc)
     values(clist[0],%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,clist[9],%s)""")(name,clist[3],clist[4],clist[5],clist[6],clist[7],clist[8],clist[10])
     #   print name


    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()


if(__name__=='__main__'):
    csvparsing()
```

the mysql table is

```
  Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| xbrl_id                | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| xbrl_name              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| xbrl_type              | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Xbrl_enumerations      | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Xbrl_substitutiongroup | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Xbrl_balance           | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Xbrl_periodtype        | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Xbrl_IsAbstract        | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xbrl_label             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Xbrl_desc              | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+--------------+-----
```

Comment: whats the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the error trace, it's hard to say if this is the only error, but this is certainly one error:

```
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO se_xbrl_concepts( xbrl_id,xbrl_name,xbrl_type,Xbrl_enumerations,Xbrl_substitutiongroup,Xbrl_balance, Xbrl_periodtype, Xbrl_IsAbstract,xbrl_label,Xbrl_desc)
 values(clist[0],%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,clist[9],%s)""")(name,clist[3],clist[4],clist[5],clist[6],clist[7],clist[8],clist[10])
```

You need a comma to separate your argument list from the string, and you need to move the parenthesis to the outside of that pair:

```
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO se_xbrl_concepts( xbrl_id,xbrl_name,xbrl_type,Xbrl_enumerations,Xbrl_substitutiongroup,Xbrl_balance, Xbrl_periodtype, Xbrl_IsAbstract,xbrl_label,Xbrl_desc)
 values(clist[0],%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,clist[9],%s)""",(name,clist[3],clist[4],clist[5],clist[6],clist[7],clist[8],clist[10]))
```